# How to detect window size/viewport in current sreen and on resize?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive-design

i'm in responesive design so i need a jquery plugin to detect live window viewport !

also i using [respone.js](http://responsejs.com/) with javascript code below

```
console.log(Response.viewportW());
```

and i get result is : 1280 , so when i resize window , the value still same , this will change when i refresh window only .

i need a jquery plugin detect current viewport an when resize ! and call this anywhere in javascript page ! ex : `var $winWidth = Response.viewportW()` , with $winWidth auto detect window width !

example like this site http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/ , you can see $(window).width() live output , is show 1263 and when you resize window , the value live change !

Thanks for help ! and my bad english !! Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without the plugin this will be

```
$(window).resize(function(){
console.log($(window).width())
})
```

with the plugin . please take a look at the docs

http://responsejs.com/#api

here is an example

http://jsfiddle.net/kppn6/1/

Comment: Thank for reply , i has seen a docs , so i need get R.viewportW() in another javascript file , and in my plugin !! so can i get it in another file ! Thanks Hussein !!

Comment: @PeterJack you're welcome . `R.action()` Call a function when the DOM is ready and whenever the window resizes. so it's more like `.resize()` . dont forget to accept the answer :)